# Sort by options translated only in list

Tags: magento-1.9, category, catalog

In category view the dropdown "sort by" is translated.

When I choose an option, the default one turns into English

[image]

Answer (score 0):

"manufacturer" is probably a product attribute - try changing its label from `Catalog -> Products -> Attributes -> Manage Attributes -> (search for manufacturer) -> Manage Label / Options`

Comment: Hello and thanks for the respnse
The label is correctly translated.
I think that it is showing attribute code instead of label. How this can be changed?